# How to add aspx views to ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I have a project MVC 5 that uses and has many aspx engine views .aspx, I added new functionality to the controllers, however, when I click on add view only razor pages are available. Is there a component I'm missing?

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community edition.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that newer Visual Studio versions do not allow to create ASPx (WebForms) View Engine Views:

[Visual Studio 2017 - MVC Web Application Controller Add View missing ASPX rendering; only RAZOR](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87cf9775-242b-4eb6-923d-7c83106d0293/visual-studio-2017-mvc-web-application-controller-add-view-missing-aspx-rendering-only-razor)

You can try to create the required ones (the ASPX files with the corrected directives) in older VS version and Copy/Past them into your VS 2019 project and try to compile. However, now it is necessary to use the Razor View Engine View instead.